# Need to write query for Date logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a below query which have a date filter like `EST_PICK_DATE between '2015-02-01' and '2015-06-01'`, where the logic is `EST_PICK_DATE` should be 3 months from the current month and 1st date of next month. 
I.E  for current month MAY, `EST_PICK_DATE` should be between `'2015-02-01'` and `'2015-06-01'`.
I need to write below query dynamically.
In below query i have hardcoded the values `'2015-02-01'` and `'2015-06-01'`, but it should take dynamically.
How to achieve this? I am using this query in SSIS package, So Shall i do in SQL level or we should implement this logic in package? If yes, How?

```
INSERT INTO STG_Open_Orders (Div_Code, net_price, gross_price)
SELECT ord.DIV_CODE AS Div_Code, ord_l.NET_PRICE AS net_price, ord_l.gross_price AS gross_price, 
FROM ORD ord inner join ORD_L ord_l ONord.ORD_ID=ord_l.ORD_ID
WHERE ord_l.EST_PICK_DATE BETWEEN '2015-02-01' AND'2015-06-01'
```

Comment: Should take dynamically what?

Comment: Use Dateadd function

Comment: Hi Giorgi,
                 It should take EST_PICK_DATE date dynamically using above logic.

Thanks

Comment: @ramu, what is input? current date? first day of current month or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO STG_Open_Orders (Div_Code, net_price, gross_price)
SELECT ord.DIV_CODE AS Div_Code, ord_l.NET_PRICE AS net_price, ord_l.gross_price AS gross_price, 
FROM ORD ord inner join ORD_L ord_l ONord.ORD_ID=ord_l.ORD_ID
WHERE ord_l.EST_PICK_DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,DATEADD(month,-3,getdate())), 0) AND DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,DATEADD(month,1,getdate())), 0)
```

here are your start date and end date function

```
SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,DATEADD(month,-3,getdate())), 0)
2015-02-01 00:00:00.000

SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,DATEADD(month,1,getdate())), 0)
2015-06-01 00:00:00.000
```

For Specific date :

```
Declare @YourDate as date = '6/3/2015' -- note the format is mm/dd/yyyy
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,DATEADD(month,-3,@YourDate)), 0) as date)
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,DATEADD(month,1,@YourDate)), 0) as date)
```

Comment: Hi Pravin,
                 Thanks for your reply,
Suppose If we in month of JUNE. Ex Today's date is June 3rd, So it should take EST_PICK_DATE between '2015-03-01' and '2015-07-01'. will above logic work for this?

Comment: Yes it should .. Ideally it will calculate as per date we have specified.. now we are using getdate(), instead you can put @yourdate to check.

Comment: Hi praveen,
                     I need EST_PICK_DATE in date format like '2015-02-01'. I tried this 

select DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,DATEADD(month,-3,CONVERT(DATE, getdate()))), 0)

but it gives me '2015-02-01 00:00:00.000' but i need '2015-02-01', Where I am wrong here?

Comment: You need to use cast to convert datetime to date For e.g., SELECT CAST(DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,DATEADD(month,-3,@YourDate)), 0) as date)
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,DATEADD(month,1,@YourDate)), 0) as date)

Comment: But this should not matter unless you are using it in 'SELECT' query

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`GETDATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) and some sql tricks to get the first day of the month:

```
INSERT INTO STG_Open_Orders (Div_Code, net_price, gross_price)
SELECT ord.DIV_CODE AS Div_Code, 
       ord_l.NET_PRICE AS net_price, 
       ord_l.gross_price AS gross_price, 
FROM ORD ord 
inner join ORD_L ord_l ONord.ORD_ID=ord_l.ORD_ID
WHERE ord_l.EST_PICK_DATE BETWEEN 
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-3, 0) -- first day 3 months ago
AND 
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0) -- first day next month
```

Comment: Thanks zohar,
       praveen's answer has worked for me...Thanks for your valuable time.....

Comment: It's basically the same answer... as long as the problem is solved nobody's time was wasted :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this (according to current date from system):

```
    SELECT ord.DIV_CODE AS Div_Code, ord_l.NET_PRICE AS net_price, ord_l.gross_price AS gross_price, 
    FROM ORD ord inner join ORD_L ord_l ONord.ORD_ID=ord_l.ORD_ID
    WHERE ord_l.EST_PICK_DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate())-3, 0) AND DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate())+1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Arkadiusz,
       praveen's answer has worked for me...Thanks for your valuable time.....